# Error when trying to access nativeLibraryDir

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

i'm trying to access getPackageManager.getApplicationInfo in jni.

```
const char* getNativeLibPath(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, const char* libraryName, const char* packageName) {
    jclass contextClass = env->GetObjectClass(thiz);
    jmethodID getPackageManager = env->GetMethodID(contextClass, "getPackageManager", "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");
    jobject instantiatePackageManager = env->CallObjectMethod(thiz, getPackageManager);
    jclass packageManagerClass = env->GetObjectClass(instantiatePackageManager);
    jmethodID getApplicationInfo = env->GetMethodID(packageManagerClass, "getApplicationInfo", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;");
    jobject instantiateApplicationInfo = env->CallObjectMethod(thiz, getApplicationInfo, packageName, 0);
    jclass applicationInfoClass = env->GetObjectClass(instantiateApplicationInfo);
    jfieldID nativeLibraryDir = env->GetFieldID(applicationInfoClass, "nativeLibraryDir", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    auto string = (jstring) env->GetObjectField(instantiateApplicationInfo, nativeLibraryDir);
    const char* returnValue = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, nullptr);
    std::string appendedResult = std::string(returnValue) + std::string("/") + std::string(libraryName);
    return appendedResult.c_str();
}
```

This is my code for it. However for some reason i'm getting this error: `JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale WeakGlobal 0x74eecd21ff  (index 1324143135 in a table of size 38) JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted weak global reference 0x74eecd21ff`
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has at least three problems:

1. You call `getApplicationInfo` with a `const char *` which expects a Java string:

```
jobject instantiateApplicationInfo = env->CallObjectMethod(instantiatePackageManager, getApplicationInfo, env->NewStringUTF(packageName), 0);
```

2. You need to call `env->ReleaseStringUTF(returnValue)` to release the string on the Java side
3. You cannot return a `const char *` like that. Either return the `std::string` directly, or allocate memory with `new char[]` and let the caller free it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! For some reason, i get this error when using your answer: ```jobject instantiateApplicationInfo = env->CallObjectMethod(thiz, getApplicationInfo, env->NewStringUTF(packageName), 0);``` the error i get is: ```JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(java.lang.String, int) on instance of com.arc.dlopenhook.MainActivity```

Comment: Thanks for the other suggestions too!

Comment: I just copied that line from your code and added the `NewStringUTF`. In hindsight, that `thiz` should probably be the package manager instead. See edit.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thank you so much!